# Resolve Google Crawl Index error

Tags: html, google-search-console

Here is one of my help topics:

http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/public_talks/HelpOnline/source/congregationlink.htm

[image: Snippet]

In that topic is the following HTML code:

```
<li>
    <p align="left">You might have a file 
    your computer with directions and details, in which case you could
    use a <a href="file://path_to_file.doc">file://path_to_file.doc</a> link.</p>
</li>
```

Now, I have only just noticed that in The Google Search Console it has raised a [crawl index error](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203):

[image: Crawl Index Error]

The information in the help topic is only a **visual example** for the user and **not literal HTML**. How can I change this HTML so that it still **looks** the same but supresses the crawl index error?

I am essentially wanting to show the user an example of what they could type in that edit box should they desire to link to a local file.

As you can see, I actually provide three examples to the user. But they were all literal links as I did not know how to represent them as examples without turning them into literal links.

Comment: Seriously? link to local? `file://path_to_file.doc` this link not working and Google recognized it as *not found* so you get error until you fix it.

Comment: I know that!!! Did you read my question?  It is not a literal link. It is indicative to the user. Basically, it is just text. So it needs changing.

Comment: Not clear enough to me, what I see, you linked a local file, and got error from Google, so what do you want exactly? fix the error? so fix the link or make it `nofollow noindex` If I wrong, make it clear.

Comment: @Pedram Please see updated question.

Comment: Well the quickest fix would be trivial - change to `href="#"`, that should still keep the formatting for a link applied, without actually referring to something Google “can’t see”.

Comment: There must be an accepted standard for some HTML as text, kind of like formatted code here in questions.

Answer (score 1):

You might try that.

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
<li>
    <p align="left">You might have a file 
    your computer with directions and details, in which case you could
    use a <a href="file://path_to_file.doc">file://path_to_file.doc</a> link.</p>
</li>
<!--googleon: index>
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see updated question. I think I need to change the code in some way so it is not a literal link.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the HTML logic like this:

```
<p align="left">1. Keep a set of directions to a Kingdom Hall:</p>
<pre> www.streetmap.co.uk</pre>
<p align="left">2. Keep the coordinator or speakers email address:</p>
<pre>mailto:email@address.com</pre>
<p align="left">3. You might have a file on your computer with directions and details:</p>
<pre align="left">file://path_to_file.doc</pre>
```

[image: Results]